# Confirm transaction in regtest mode

Tags: client, bitcoin-cli, regtest, dash, transaction-id

I'm testing some wallet features on regtest. Here's the sequence so far:

```
cash-cli -regtest generate 101
cash-cli -regtest getbalance
500.00000000

cash-cli -regtest getnewaddress newAddress1
yeAPxkjsNk5RZnAyfHM6cjCtKM7oRUvhzX

cash-cli -regtest  sendtoaddress getrawtransaction 148b8ced78037cb8fe3b32b8814dbf6736c144448671a86da548bbdb5670750a 1
//...
{
      "value": 2.00000000,
      "valueSat": 200000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 c3bc1c481a15343ceb27d45d950c8770b7a0be1c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914c3bc1c481a15343ceb27d45d950c8770b7a0be1c88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "yeAPxkjsNk5RZnAyfHM6cjCtKM7oRUvhzX"
        ]
      }
    }, 
//...

dash-cli -regtest gettxout 148b8ced78037cb8fe3b32b8814dbf6736c144448671a86da548bbdb5670750a 0 false
//returns nothing as the transaction is not confirmed. Returns result if we change flag to true
```

How do I set transaction as confirmed in regtest mode so that `dash-cli -regtest <txid> <outid> false` would return the transaction output as a valid one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is confirmed by including it in a block. This means that you have to mine a block which includes the transaction. You can do this using the `generate` command.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: `cash-cli -regtest generate 6` will create 6 blocks with the block reward going to your wallet.

Comment: I create and send raw transaction then use `generatetoaddress` to mine blocks to get confirmations but the sent transactions stays unconfirmed. Any idea why?

Comment: @Fontaine did you ever find out what your problem was? I have the same, currently.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm facing the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running `bitcoind` along with Bitcore-node and I was having the same problem. I sent 250 transactions to myself, but the balance I got from BWC/BWS was:

```
{
  "totalAmount": 166250000000,
  "lockedAmount": 0,
  "totalConfirmedAmount": 0,
  "lockedConfirmedAmount": 0,
  "availableAmount": 166250000000,
  "availableConfirmedAmount": 0,
  "byAddress": [
    {
      "address": "mvaTRJ63NJrZ3qaZW1AbfVzMsei5HCiupb",
      "path": "m/0/0",
      "amount": 166250000000
    }
  ]
}
```

Apparently, `bitcoind` will hold a cache in memory and it takes some time (or more actions) to release it, passing its contents to the database.

When you close the process (say, with CTRL+C or CMD+C), you'll see a message like this:

```
2020-10-22T12:23:57Z FlushStateToDisk: write coins cache to disk (250 coins, 34kB) started 
2020-10-22T12:23:57Z FlushStateToDisk: write coins cache to disk (250 coins, 34kB) completed (0.05s)
```

Then, Bitcore-node will sync and save everything in MongoDb. So, if you close the
`bitcoind` process and then restart, your transactions should become confirmed.

Here's exactly what I did:

1. Start `bitcoind` in regtest mode:
   `bitcoind -printtoconsole -regtest -fallbackfee=0.00001`
2. Start Bitcore-node. I assume you have it configured to point to your regtest node.
   `npm run node`
3. Generate 250 transactions to myself:
   `bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress 250 "mvaTRJ63NJrZ3qaZW1AbfVzMsei5HCiupb"`
4. Wait for Bitcore to sync with `bitcoind`.
5. Close `bitcoind` with CTRL+C (or CMD+C).
6. Close Bitcore-node with CTRL+C (or CMD+C).
7. Restart `bitcoind` and Bitcore-node.
8. Boom. Using BWC and BWS to fetch the wallet's balance I now receive this:

```
{
 "totalAmount":166250000000,
 "lockedAmount":0,
 "totalConfirmedAmount":166250000000,
 "lockedConfirmedAmount":0,
 "availableAmount":166250000000,
 "availableConfirmedAmount":166250000000,
 "byAddress":[
  {
   "address":"mvaTRJ63NJrZ3qaZW1AbfVzMsei5HCiupb",
   "path":"m/0/0",
   "amount":166250000000
  }
 ]
}
```